Tiptap Editor Extend Link for Atom
I was creating a small comment box using tiptap editor and I wanted the link to be directly not editable, the documentation says if the atom for any extension is true, you cannot directly edit it which is what I exactly want. So, I found that we can extend the existing extension and set the atom as true.
import Link from '@tiptap/extension-link';
const customLink = Link.extend({
  atom: true,
  draggable: true,
});

Here are the sources,
extend: https://tiptap.dev/docs/editor/guide/custom-extensions
schema: https://tiptap.dev/docs/editor/api/schema#atom
Here is some example code
new Editor({
   content: this.initialContent,
   extensions: [
      StarterKit,
      Underline,
      customLink.configure({
          openOnClick: false,
          autolink: true,
          linkOnPaste: true,
          rel: 'noopener noreferrer',
          HTMLAttributes: {
            class: 'links',
          },
      })
   ]
})

I want this link to be not editable directly. If the link is in comment box, it has to be entirely deleted or not be editable once entered. Any clues what I am doing wrong?
(I am using vue2 and tiptap: 2.1.15)

Can you create a sandbox/fiddle link so that it would be easier to help you?
